# Two quadratic programming problems always same answer?

Tags: quadratic-forms, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming

Was exploring quadratic programming optimization and for two types of problems the answers seemed to always equal.

Problem 1:

- Minimize $\tfrac{1}{2} \mathbf{x}^T Q\mathbf{x}$
- Subject to $ A \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b} $ and $\mathbf{x}>0$
- $ Q = n \mathbf{I}_{(n,n)} - \mathbf{1}_{(n,n)}$
- Call the solution $\widehat{\mathbf{x}}$

Problem 2:

- Define $ S_R = R \mathbf{I}_{(n,n)} - \mathbf{1}_{(n,n)}$ for scalar $0<R<n$
- Maximum R such that there exist a non-trivial solution $\mathbf{x}$ such that  $\tfrac{1}{2} \mathbf{x}^T S_R\mathbf{x}=0$
- Subject to $ A \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b} $ and $\mathbf{x}>0$  (same as Problem 1)
- Call the solution of $\mathbf{x}$ for the maximum R to be $\widetilde{\mathbf{x}}$

Is it always true that $\widehat{\mathbf{x}}$ = $\widetilde{\mathbf{x}}$ ?

Comment: $$\mathbf x^TS_R\mathbf x=\sum_{i,j}(x_i-x_j)^2+(R-3)\sum_ix_i^2$$